# Saving uploaded files with element-UI and Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, element-ui

I need to save the uploaded files when i click the Salveaza button with element-UI and vue.js.All i have for now is this piece of code:

````
<span :md="12" class="m-md">
            <el-form-item label="Incarcare Document" >
              <el-upload
                :on-preview="handlePreview"
                :on-remove="handleRemove"
                :file-list="fileList"
                :auto-upload="false"
                class="upload-demo"
                drag
                multiple>
                <i class="el-icon-upload"/>
                <div class="el-upload__text">Drop file here or <em>click to upload</em></div>
                <div slot="tip" class="el-upload__tip">jpg/png files with a size less than 500kb</div>
              </el-upload>
            </el-form-item>
          </span>
```[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9D2zU.png
````